# Acoustic Model Training Error in Sphinx

Tags: cmusphinx

I have created all the files needed and put them in the right folder hierarchy. After the configuration file is created, I modify it as needed and then start the training but errors occur in the terminal as shown:

```
Sphinxtrain path: /usr/local/lib/sphinxtrain
Sphinxtrain binaries path: /usr/local/libexec/sphinxtrain
Running the training
MODULE: 000 Computing feature from audio files
Extracting features from  segments starting at  (part 1 of 1) 
Extracting features from  segments starting at  (part 1 of 1) 
Feature extraction is done
MODULE: 00 verify training files
    Phase 1: Checking to see if the dict and filler dict agrees with the phonelist file.
WARNING: The phonelist (/home/anonymus/workspace/Sphinx-Test/Alphabets/tutorial/alphabets/etc/alphabets.phone) does not define the phone SIL (required!)
        Found 6 words using 10 phones
WARNING: This phone (SIL) occurs in the dictionary (/home/anonymus/workspace/Sphinx-Test/Alphabets/tutorial/alphabets/etc/alphabets.dic), but not in the phonelist (/home/anonymus/workspace/Sphinx-Test/Alphabets/tutorial/alphabets/etc/alphabets.phone)
    Phase 2: Checking to make sure there are not duplicate entries in the dictionary
    Phase 3: Check general format for the fileids file; utterance length (must be positive); files exist
    Phase 4: Checking number of lines in the transcript file should match lines in fileids file
    Phase 5: Determine amount of training data, see if n_tied_states seems reasonable.
        Estimated Total Hours Training: 0.000816666666666667
        This is a small amount of data, no comment at this time
    Phase 6: Checking that all the words in the transcript are in the dictionary
        Words in dictionary: 3
        Words in filler dictionary: 3
    Phase 7: Checking that all the phones in the transcript are in the phonelist, and all phones in the phonelist appear at least once
MODULE: 0000 train grapheme-to-phoneme model
Skipped (set $CFG_G2P_MODEL = 'yes' to enable)
MODULE: 01 Train LDA transformation
Skipped (set $CFG_LDA_MLLT = 'yes' to enable)
MODULE: 02 Train MLLT transformation
Skipped (set $CFG_LDA_MLLT = 'yes' to enable)
MODULE: 05 Vector Quantization
Skipped for continuous models
MODULE: 10 Training Context Independent models for forced alignment and VTLN
Skipped:  $ST::CFG_FORCEDALIGN set to 'no' in sphinx_train.cfg
Skipped:  $ST::CFG_VTLN set to 'no' in sphinx_train.cfg
MODULE: 11 Force-aligning transcripts
Skipped:  $ST::CFG_FORCEDALIGN set to 'no' in sphinx_train.cfg
MODULE: 12 Force-aligning data for VTLN
Skipped:  $ST::CFG_VTLN set to 'no' in sphinx_train.cfg
MODULE: 20 Training Context Independent models
    Phase 1: Cleaning up directories:
    accumulator...logs...qmanager...models...
    Phase 2: Flat initialize
    Phase 3: Forward-Backward
        Baum welch starting for 1 Gaussian(s), iteration: 1 (1 of 1)
        0% 
Only 0 parts of 1 of Baum Welch were successfully completed
Parts 1 failed to run!
Training failed in iteration 1
MODULE: 30 Training Context Dependent models
    Phase 1: Cleaning up directories:
    accumulator...logs...qmanager...
    Phase 2: Initialization
This step had 1 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
    Phase 3: Forward-Backward
        Baum welch starting for iteration: 1 (1 of 1) 
        0% 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 2 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
Only 0 parts of 1 of Baum Welch were successfully completed
Parts 1 failed to run!
Training failed in iteration 1
MODULE: 40 Build Trees
    Phase 1: Cleaning up old log files...
    Phase 2: Make Questions
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
    Phase 3: Tree building
        Processing each phone with each state
        AE 0 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        AE 1 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        AE 2 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        L 0 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        L 1 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        L 2 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        AH 0 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        AH 1 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        AH 2 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        F 0 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        F 1 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        F 2 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        B 0 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        B 1 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        B 2 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        IY 0 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        IY 1 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        IY 2 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        JH 0 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        JH 1 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        JH 2 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        EY 0 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        EY 1 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        EY 2 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        M 0 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        M 1 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        M 2 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
MODULE: 45 Prune Trees
    Phase 1: Tree Pruning
This step had 1 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
    Phase 2: State Tying
This step had 1 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
MODULE: 50 Training Context dependent models
    Phase 1: Cleaning up directories:
    accumulator...logs...qmanager...
    Phase 2: Copy CI to CD initialize
This step had 1 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
    Phase 3: Forward-Backward
        Baum welch starting for 1 Gaussian(s), iteration: 1 (1 of 1)
        0% 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
Only 0 parts of 1 of Baum Welch were successfully completed
Parts 1 failed to run!
Training failed in iteration 1
MODULE: 60 Lattice Generation
Skipped:  $ST::CFG_MMIE set to 'no' in sphinx_train.cfg
MODULE: 61 Lattice Pruning
Skipped:  $ST::CFG_MMIE set to 'no' in sphinx_train.cfg
MODULE: 62 Lattice Format Conversion
Skipped:  $ST::CFG_MMIE set to 'no' in sphinx_train.cfg
MODULE: 65 MMIE Training
Skipped:  $ST::CFG_MMIE set to 'no' in sphinx_train.cfg
MODULE: 90 deleted interpolation
Skipped for continuous models
MODULE: DECODE Decoding using models previously trained
        Decoding 3 segments starting at 0 (part 1 of 1) 
        0% 
This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
        Aligning results to find error rate
word_align.pl failed with error code 65280 at /usr/local/lib/sphinxtrain/scripts/decode/slave.pl line 173.
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues which logs report you about:

> WARNING: This phone (SIL) occurs in the dictionary (/home/anonymus/workspace/Sphinx-Test/Alphabets/tutorial/alphabets/etc/alphabets.dic), but not in the phonelist (/home/anonymus/workspace/Sphinx-Test/Alphabets/tutorial/alphabets/etc/alphabets.phone)

You need to add SIL phone to alphabets.phone file.

> Estimated Total Hours Training: 0.000816666666666667

You do not have enough data for training. A starting amount is 1 hour of data. You can find details in acoustic model training tutorial

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam

Comment: Actually I am making an acoustic model for Arabic alphabets. So the recordings can't reach one hour. So what should I do regarding that?

Comment: You can record letters several times. It's mandatory to have 1 hour of audio.

Comment: so each letter repeated in one file for one hour and there's 28 letters in Arabic so that means 28 hours of recording ,right? Or should it be all the letters in one file?

Comment: This question might be out of the subject, but is it possible to use pocketsphinx for non-android platforms?

Comment: Yes, sure, pocketsphinx is successfully used on different platforms including Windows Phone and Blackberry for example, Raspberry Pi too.

Comment: If you can tell me the way to implement in a java project on windows or Linux, that would be highly appreciated!!!

Comment: If you want java, I recommend you to try sphinx4.